# C#: sql table data text has '?' in place of 'é' after copy

Tags: c#, .net, sql, encoding

I am doing a SQL table data copy. First I am getting all the data from a csv file (which is got from a sql table) in the csv file I get 'é' correctly, but when I insert it in the table then I'm getting '?' in the sql table. I don't use any encoding, so everything is default. Somebody knows why this happens?

SOLVED:

Needed to read the csv like this:

`string[] csvlines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\export.csv",Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"));`

Thanks

Comment: Transfer from where to where? How are you transferring? When encoding is the source in? What encoding are you using on the target? Please post your current code.

Comment: you should use the Encoding that you specified when creating the SQL table. For a list of (provided) Encodings in .NET look ==> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Comment: I agree that the question is of poor quality, but IMHO it can be improved through editing. After a (good) edit it quite possibly will be a good source for future developers with the same problem. 
tl;dr: Would the downvoter please explain why he downvoted ?

Comment: like to @yas4891. +1 for open-minded

Comment: @yas4891 - If and when the question will be salvaged, I will reverse the downvote. I don't believe this is answerable in its current form.

Comment: OK, can this topic be deleted so I can create a one with a lot more information (I need to search for)  thanks

Comment: But no one will look at it then? And it is downvoted too

Comment: Your answer is right yas! My csv is `Windows-1252` encoded. I will try to read it with the right encoding

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6760/discussion-between-ozkan-and-yas4891)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you should use whatever encoding was used when the table was created (or last modified - *for the nitpickers*).
If you are transferring data between different tables you possibly need to use different encodings for reading and writing data.

The .NET framework provides a rich list of implemented encodings, which you can find below this type: [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)

**UPDATE**

Please use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to determine the encoding of the .CSV-file you are reading data from. Then use that Encoding in the constructor of your [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx) object.

So *if* Notepad++ tells you that the file is encoded in *UTF-8*, use the following lines of code to read from your file:

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("myCSVfile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.UTF8)
{
  // read file content here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN:An encoding for the operating system's current ANSI code page.
I recommend you to use `nvarchar` and `nchar` data type in database and use `N` before string value like: N'الله'

Answer (score 0):

I think its UTF-8 you are looking for this char é.

I am not too familiar with c# but this link looks to be a good start

http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/utf8encodingdefault-encodingutf8-net-c/
From article:

> Looks like UTF8Encoding.Default would return a default instance of the
>   UTF8Encoding, right?
>
> Well, it doesn’t – it returns the operating system’s default ANSI
>   encoding.
>
> The same with ASCIIEncoding.Default, UnicodeEncoding.Default,
>   UTF32Encoding.Default and UTF7Encoding.Default!
>
> Why? Because they all derive from System.Text.Encoding where Default
>   is definded:

Comment: How do you deduce that it is UTF-8 (and not Unicode / UTF-16 / some other encoding) from the fact that the character is é ?

Comment: To be honest I was making a guess based on what I have experienced in the past.  I have had issues reading special characters from an MSSQL DB before. Often times its because the default encoding was not UTF-8 (Latin-1 for example). I think I may have misinterpreted your question originally.